# set Delegate to Subclass of NSImageView placed in Xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, delegates

I have an `NSImageView` subclass that I use for dragging and dropping Files onto in my app.

To do this I created a subclass of `NSImageView` and also dragged the `NSImageView` onto my XIB,  I then set the class of the XIB `NSImageView` Object to my custom subclass.

Everything works well with the drag and drop and I know I have the correct file after the drag.

The problem comes in when I want to update a textfield on the MainViewController based on the file dragged in.

I created the following subclass and protocol

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>

@protocol PDFDraggedIntoWell <NSObject>
@required
-(void)PDFDraggedIntoWellWithURL:(NSURL*) importedURL;

@end


@interface DragAndDropImageView : NSImageView

@property (strong) id <PDFDraggedIntoWell> delegate;

@end
```

Then in my implementation in the subclass I try to call the delegate method

```
-(void) finishedDragginInFileWithURL:(NSURL*) importedURL{
    if( self.delegate != nil && [ self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(PDFDraggedIntoWellWithURL:)]) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(PDFDraggedIntoWellWithURL:) withObject:importedURL];
    }
}
```

The problem I run into is how do you assign the delegate.  From the XIB NSImageView to my MainviewController I connect up an `IBOutlet`

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet DragAndDropImageView *draggedFileImageView;
```

And I have declared that my ViewController will receive the delegate

```
@interface MyMainUIViewController ()<PDFDraggedIntoWell>
```

with the appropriate method implemented

```
-(void) PDFDraggedIntoWellWithURL:(NSURL *)importedURL{   }
```

Now I have tried in various places to assign delegate to self (in `viewDidLoad` - which doesn’t get called since the view is being loaded in a XIB??) and also in

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

but all I get back is the delegate is still nil when debugging.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is `MyMainUIViewController` defined as a subclass of (`NSObject`, `NSWindowController`, `NSViewController`, etc.)?

Comment: it is a NSViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using xibx the `initWithCoder` method is called for initialization. Set your delegate there.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
        myView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Alternatively set the delegate via interface builder by dragging wile holding ctrl from the File's Owner to your view. Like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Pfitz,  Where would the initwithCoder method go?  In my mainviewcontroller?  if it goes in the subclassed NSImageView implementation how would it know which class the delegate needs to refer to?  Also my IB doesn’t show delegate as one of the available outlets? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add add the delegate to the awakefromnib(in mymainviewcontroller) method and things are working fine now.  Thanks